# Publish website on the internet with own PC

Tags: html, tomcat, ip, port, publish

I have some simple HTML page (code below) which i want to publish on the Internet hosted with my PC. It's just for testing purposes so i don't need a static IP or high uptimes or any fancy stuff.

First of all I installed Tomcat Apache and put my WAR in the webapps folder.
After that i could reach my website through: `localhost:8080/simpletest/`.

After that i forwarded port 80 and port 8080 in my router settings binded to my internal IP address which is `192.168.0.16`.
I can access those ports now successfully on http://www.canyouseeme.org/ after configuring my firewall and so on.

Now i tried to reach this website with my cellphone mobile internet through my current external IP address. I tried these addresses but i can't access my website:
 http://46.128.22.113:8080/
http://46.128.22.113:8080/simpletest/
http://46.128.22.113

All the tutorials i followed did that steps and it worked for them but not for me. Can someone see what I am doing wrong?

My fancy website index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
sdffdsfdfdsfdsfdsfd
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solved it myself. If someone else has the same problem i hope it helps. Port 8080 just didn't work on the web but i don't know why. Perhaps because my router uses it for remote control. So i changed the tomcat port to 8181 and it worked.